# Outlook showing several times email send by Amazon SES

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Every day we send several emails using Amazon SES to our customers. Only one of them receives 2 or 3 times the same email. She sent me copies of those email and the header messageid is the same. In fact we reviewed her web mail portal and there she received only 1 copy of the email.

It is clear that Outlook (her email client) is doing something strange, however, I do not have any idea which configuration can produce that behavior.

Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Has this customer requested assistance from their IT Department?

Comment: @Ramhound. They do not have an IT department. We made a call with the email provider and they confirm what I described in the question. As part of our service we are trying to help her,  however, the problem is strange.

Answer (score 0):

The customer should look at *Rules* for the Inbox, which might automatically be *copying* an incoming message to a particular folder. If there is more than one rule, e.g., "copy email where Sender is like '@Ayorus'", "copy email where Subject is 'AyorusProduct'".

Another possibility is that the same email is sent to another worker, e.g., her manager, and that person has enabled copy of email to her.

As you surmise, if everyone else gets only a single copy, the issue is more *likely* at the recipient's end. However, I'd also double-check that extra copies are not being sent from your firm... it would be embarrassing to blame her Outlook setup, only to find later that there's a duplicate line in the code that generates email!

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of your account? POP, IMAP or Exchange?
According to your description, everything could work fine on the web mail and the issue only happens in Outlook desktop client. So, seems that the issue is more related the Outlook desktop client. As I know, corrupted local data file might cause isssues like this. In order to conduct further researches, it is suggested to remove your data file and use a new Outlook data file to see if the issue could be resolved.

Comment: The account is POP. We ask the customer to change it to IMAP but she did no agree. So I think, we will not spend more time on this issue. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: It's Okay. Best regards.